# Process Observable on background thread

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I am using *RxAndroid* for stream operations. In my real use-case, i am fetching a list from the server (using *Retrofit*). I am using schedulers to do the work on a background thread and get the final emission on the Android UI (main) thread.

This works well for the network call, however i realized that my operators after the network call do not use the background thread, but getting called on the main thread.

```
myService.fetchSomeIntegersFromServer()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .filter(integer -> {
            System.out.println(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread());
            return true;
        })
        .subscribe(integer1 -> {});
```

How can i make sure that all operations are executed on a background thread?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**TL;DR**: move `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` below `filter(...)`.

---

`subscribeOn(...)` is used to designate on which thread the `Observable` will *begin* operating on. Subsequent calls to `subscribeOn` will be ignored.

Thus, if you were to write the following, *everything* would be executed on `Schedulers.newThread()`:

```
myService.fetchSomeIntegersFromServer()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .filter(integer -> {
            System.out.println(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread());
            return true;
        })
        .subscribe(integer1 -> { doSomething(integer1); });
```

Now, of course, this is not what you want: you want to `doSomething` on the main thread.
That is where `observeOn` comes into place. All actions *after* `observeOn` are executed on that scheduler. Therefore, in your example, the `filter` is executed on the main thread.

Instead, move `observeOn` down to just before `subscribe`:

```
myService.fetchSomeIntegersFromServer()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .filter(integer -> {
            System.out.println(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread());
            return true;
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(integer1 -> { doSomething(integer1) });
```

Now, `filter` will happen on the 'new thread', and `doSomething` on the main thread.

---

To go even further, you can use `observeOn` multiple times:

```
myService.fetchSomeIntegersFromServer()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .filter(integer -> {
            System.out.println(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread());
            return true;
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(integer1 -> { doSomething(integer1) });
```

In this case, the fetching will occur on a new thread, the filtering on a computation thread, and `doSomething` on the main thread.

Checkout [ReactiveX - SubscribeOn operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html) for the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Is there a way to define the schedulers at the start of the method call chain (like in the OP)?

Comment: The Observables follow the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), so by design, that is not possible. `observeOn` (and the other methods) do not return the same `Observable` instance like the builder pattern does, but instead return a _new_ `Observable` 'wrapping' the 'old' `Observable`.

Comment: I understand that. This is unfortunate for the case, because that means i have to add the `observeOn()` call to every stream i write? :(

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: If i want to fetch and filter another list from the server, i also have to add the `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` line. (Currently i am caching the observable, and i thought that the first `observeOn()` call will take care.)

Comment: Ah, I see. If caching the `Observable` returned by Retrofit that way is allowed, then you should be able to cache the entire chain up to (not including) `subscribe`? Subsequent calls could use that cached `Observable` again, already containing `observeOn(mainThread())`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93544/discussion-between-wondercsabo-and-nhaarman).

Comment: Awesomely detailed and helpful answer. Thank you.

Comment: great answer, 10x!